# How can I indicate the levels of possibility with the word "chance"?

Tags: sentence-construction

How can I indicate the levels of possibility with the word "**chance**"?

All I know is that I can say "There's much of a chance I'm going to marry her" when possibility is high.

How about these sentences?

> 1. There's a lot of chance a chance ~
> 2. There's low chance ~
> 3. There's high chance ~

I just want to know as many common expressions with the word **"Chance"** as possible

Comment: I'm afraid you would not want to say, "There's much of a chance", because this would be unidiomatic: the phrase is used in negative statements like "**I don't think** there's much of a chance..." or "There's **not** much of a chance that she could have a child and not miss school."

Comment: @CopperKettle Oh~ yes!. actually the original sentence is "I figured I didn't have much of a chance". Do we usually say "much of a Noun" in a negative sentence?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I suspect it might be one of the so-called **[negative polarity items](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarity_item)**

Comment: @jihoon One could use **not much of a** ***noun*** to specify a **diminutive** of the noun with a probable negative connotation. He's **not much of an** athlete. That's **not much of a** car.

Answer (score 1):

Some descriptive adjectives for **chance** (from high to low, with some possible overlap)

> **incredible** chance
>   **huge** chance
>   **big** chance
>   **high** chance
>   **better** chance
>   **even** chance
>   **moderate** chance
>   **low** chance
>   **not so good** chance
>   **slight** chance
>   **no** chance

One can use many different adjectives describing size or height as a modifier for **chance**.  Much of the time, a native would use an **adj+chance**(s) **construction**, however some **modifiers** would sound more native as an **adjective phrase**.

> There is a **slight chance** for rain.
>   The **chances** for a good weekend are **not so good**.
>   You have **no chance** to win the lottery.
>   This is your **big chance**!

Comment: Can I use 'slim' or 'thin'?